# How to stop the Tic Tac Toe js

Tags: javascript

I would like to stop my Tic Tac Toe when it ends so that we can no longer place a cross or a circle.

Currently, after there is a winner, one can still click the remaining empty boxes. How can I disable the click event after the game is over?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Anouar34/bjgfut71/, or see below.

```js
let i = 0;
    const cases = document.querySelectorAll('.case');
    function tour() {
      i++;
      return i % 2 === 0 ? 'O' :  'X';
    }

    function afficherGagnant(gagnant) {
      document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML =`The ${gagnant} player is winner !`;
      document.querySelector('.gameStatus').style.display = "block";
    }


    function isGagner() {
      if (cases[0].innerHTML !== '' && cases[0].innerHTML === cases[1].innerHTML && cases[1].innerHTML === cases[2].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[0].innerHTML);
      }

      if (cases[3].innerHTML !== '' && cases[3].innerHTML === cases[4].innerHTML && cases[4].innerHTML === cases[5].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[3].innerHTML);
      }

      if (cases[6].innerHTML !== '' && cases[6].innerHTML === cases[7].innerHTML && cases[7].innerHTML === cases[8].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[6].innersHTML);
      }

      if (cases[0].innerHTML !== '' && cases[0].innerHTML === cases[3].innerHTML && cases[3].innerHTML === cases[6].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[0].innerHTML);
      }

      if (cases[1].innerHTML !== '' && cases[1].innerHTML === cases[4].innerHTML && cases[4].innerHTML === cases[7].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[1].innerHTML);
      }

      if (cases[2].innerHTML !== '' && cases[2].innerHTML === cases[5].innerHTML && cases[5].innerHTML === cases[8].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[2].innerHTML);
      }

      if (cases[0].innerHTML !== '' && cases[0].innerHTML === cases[4].innerHTML && cases[4].innerHTML === cases[8].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[0].innerHTML);
      }

      if (cases[2].innerHTML !== '' && cases[2].innerHTML === cases[4].innerHTML && cases[4].innerHTML === cases[6].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[2].innerHTML);
      }
   }

    function play() {
       if (!this.innerHTML) {
         this.innerHTML = tour();
         isGagner();
       }
    }

    cases.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', play));
```

```css
.box{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      min-height: 100vh;

      font-family: monospace;
      font-size: 36px;

      border: 5px solid black;
    }

    .morpion{
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      min-width: 50vh;
      height: 50vh;
    }

    .case{
      width: 32.5%;
      height: 33%;
      border: 1px solid #FB1;

      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .gameStatus{
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: verndana,sans-serif;
      padding: 100px 10px;
      display: none;
    }

    a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      border: 2px solid;
      border-radius: 30px;
      padding: 5px 20px;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }

    a:hover{
      background: black;
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box">
      <div class="gameStatus">
        <p id="test"></p>
      <a href="#">Replay</a>
      </div>
      <div class="morpion">
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you need to provide [mcve] here.Not a link

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note that the fiddle is better expanded to full page to get the original 3x3 layout (or css needs a fix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite it was not a complete description, i tried your jsfiddle and quickest you can do is add a var gameFinished and if true, do not play.

Note that I have not applied any special/additional logic/enhancement to your

```js
let i = 0;
var gameover = false;
    const cases = document.querySelectorAll('.case');
    function tour() {
      i++;
      return i % 2 === 0 ? 'O' :  'X';
    }

    function afficherGagnant(gagnant) {
      document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML =`The ${gagnant} player is winner !`;
      document.querySelector('.gameStatus').style.display = "block";
      gameover=true;
    }


    function isGagner() {
    if(gameover===true)
    {
       return;
    }
        if (cases[0].innerHTML !== '' && cases[0].innerHTML === cases[1].innerHTML && cases[1].innerHTML === cases[2].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[0].innerHTML);
      }

      if (cases[3].innerHTML !== '' && cases[3].innerHTML === cases[4].innerHTML && cases[4].innerHTML === cases[5].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[3].innerHTML);
      }

      if (cases[6].innerHTML !== '' && cases[6].innerHTML === cases[7].innerHTML && cases[7].innerHTML === cases[8].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[6].innersHTML);
      }

      if (cases[0].innerHTML !== '' && cases[0].innerHTML === cases[3].innerHTML && cases[3].innerHTML === cases[6].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[0].innerHTML);
      }

      if (cases[1].innerHTML !== '' && cases[1].innerHTML === cases[4].innerHTML && cases[4].innerHTML === cases[7].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[1].innerHTML);
      }

      if (cases[2].innerHTML !== '' && cases[2].innerHTML === cases[5].innerHTML && cases[5].innerHTML === cases[8].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[2].innerHTML);
      }

      if (cases[0].innerHTML !== '' && cases[0].innerHTML === cases[4].innerHTML && cases[4].innerHTML === cases[8].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[0].innerHTML);
      }

      if (cases[2].innerHTML !== '' && cases[2].innerHTML === cases[4].innerHTML && cases[4].innerHTML === cases[6].innerHTML) {
        afficherGagnant(cases[2].innerHTML);
      }
   }

    function play() {
     if(gameover===true)
    {
       return;
    }
       if (!this.innerHTML) {
         this.innerHTML = tour();
         isGagner();
       }
    }

    cases.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', play));
```

```css
.box{
         justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
      font-family: monospace;
      font-size: 36px;
      border: 5px solid black;
    }

    .morpion{
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      min-width: 50vh;
      height: 50vh;
    }

    .case{
      width: 32.5%;
      height: 33%;
      border: 1px solid #FB1;

      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .gameStatus{
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: verndana,sans-serif;
      padding: 100px 10px;
      display: none;
    }

    a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      border: 2px solid;
      border-radius: 30px;
      padding: 5px 20px;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }

    a:hover{
      background: black;
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box">
      <div class="gameStatus">
        <p id="test"></p>
      <a href="#">Replay</a>
      </div>
      <div class="morpion">
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
        <div class="case"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the even listener from all `cases` if there is a winner:

```
function isGagner() {
    if (cases...) {
       ...
       return false;
    ...
    } else {
       return true;
    }
}

function play() {
   if (!this.innerHTML) {
     this.innerHTML = tour();
     var isOver = isGagner();
     if (isOver) {
         cases.forEach(element => element.removeEventListener('click', play));
     }
   }
}
```